# #c++ Error# What's the meaning of the numbers in the terminal? cppfilename.cpp: 5:1:

Tags: c++

I'm a C++ beginner. I was confused when I saw all the errors have a similar format like `cppfilename.cpp:number: number`.

See the following figure:

[image]

Does anybody know what's the meaning of `(:5:1),(:20:3)`, and `(21:2)...`?

Comment: `(line number):(column number)`

Answer (score 0):

It's the line number and symbol number in that line - position of the error